# Is this makefile eliminating the .c file?

Tags: c, makefile

```
all: servidor
servidor: servidor.o
    gcc -lpthread -o servidor.o
servidor.o:
clean:
    gcc -c servidor.c
    rm -rf servidor.o
```

Questions:

a)Is the `clean:` line eliminating the `servidor.c` file?

b)How can I modify the makefile so that it also compiles a `client.c` program and creates a `client.o`?

Comment: If that's what the Makefile **really** looks like, I don't think it'll work at all.

Comment: That first `gcc` invocation surely cannot work as is.  It should read `gcc -o servidor servidor.o -lpthread`.

Answer (score 2):

Your entire makefile should look like this:

```
LDLIBS=-lpthread
servidor: servidor.o client.o
clean:
<TAB>rm -f *.o
```

Comment: assumes gmake, rather than e.g. AIX make.

Comment: If cc isn't a symlink to gcc, also need something like CC=/usr/bin/gcc .

Comment: Also, `-l` switches belong in LIBS, not LDFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

> a)Is the clean: line eliminating the
>   servidor.c file?

No. The line

```
gcc -c servidor.c
```

is just a lame way of ensuring `servidor.o` exists, and the subsequent `rm` does not fail. It should rather be

```
clean:
    -rm -rf servidor.o
```

> b)How can I modify the makefile so that it also compiles a client.c program and creates a client.o?

The easiest way is use built-in rules. If you add `client`, or `client.o` in any of a rule's prerequisites, it will be built automatically from `client.c`.

(and add `-lpthread` to `LDLIBS` if you need it for `client.c`)

Comment: @jpalacek Will `rm -rf` fail if the target file doesn't exist?

Comment: @khachik It may.  That's what the leading dash is for.  It tells Make to ignore the return value of the command.  (Incidentally, the `-r` switch to `rm` is unnecessary in this case (it means "recursive", and is only meaningful when applied to directories) and I would leave it out, out of paranoia.)

Answer (score 0):

the makefile seems so strange,i am not sue whether it can work or not? but i think it better as following:

```
    all: client
client: client.o
    gcc -lpthread -o client.o
client.o:
    gcc -c client.c
clean: 
    rm -rf client.o
```